# Why is the first frame of my video duplicated at the end, and being duplicated at the end of my frame extraction process using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video, camera, mp4, video-processing

I am extracting frames from a video using OpenCV. Once the process is finished and all frames are extracted, the code continues to extract the first frame of the video, seemingly infinitely.

This OpenCV code has worked for all of my videos so far except this one, which was shot with a different kind of camera, so I suspect something is different about the video file. Notably, when I play the video in Quick Time, the first frame of the video is shown at the end.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Our_Video.mp4')
i = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i)
    
    IsNotEnd, frame = cap.read()
    if IsNotEnd == False:
        break
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('increment_'+str(i)+'.png'),gray)
    i+=1
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Clearly, variable `IsNotEnd` is never being set to False – how can I change that setting from `cap.read()`? It clearly seems to relate to the first frame being shown after the video ends.

Comment: As a stopgap, I was able to determine the number of frames with `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` and then `break` the loop if `i` exceeds that value. However, any input as to how to more robustly solve the problem is still greatly appreciated, especially if there's a way to change some property of the video.

Comment: you shouldn't seek (CAP_PROP_POS*) when you read sequentially. I'd like to word that more strongly but... anyway, unless you must, do not seek.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Could you elaborate on why that matters and perhaps suggest a superior method?

Comment: simply stop doing it. and search your thoughts for why you thought read() needed extra advancing. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html (applies to video files too) -- your entire script can be replaced by a single command line invocation of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have worked with ffmpeg and unfortunately it was not able to accomplish everything I required, hence why I am using the more high-powered OpenCV. At any rate, I fixed the problem by fixing the end behavior of the video, as detailed in my answer to the post.

If you care to elaborate, with wording as strong as you wish, on why my method using (CAP_PROP_POS*) is inadequate, I would be interested. Clearly the code does not advance without this, so please review the original post carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the problem has to do with the end behavior of the video file itself. By changing the end behavior of the video file, then `cap.read()` correctly returns `False` at the final frame.